# Does clang allow preprocessor ==?

Tags: macos, clang, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to compile PHP on my Mac OS X 10.8 and I am getting the following problem:

```
In file included from /Users/ryan/Downloads/php-5.4.5/ext/phar/util.c:23:
ext/phar/phar_internal.h:223:19: error: invalid token at start of a preprocessor
      expression
# if SIZEOF_SHORT == 2
                  ^
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring as this looks fine to me. I have opened the header file and could make changes if not or remove the if all together as I know what my system should be, but I was wondering if this is the proper approach to this problem.

Comment: How is SIZEOF_SHORT defined?  clang gives the same error for "#if == 2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `SIZEOF_SHORT` expands to no tokens. You should investigate where `SIZEOF_SHORT` is being `#define`d (this may be on the command line via `-DSIZEOF_SHORT=`) and fix that to provide the right value.

Alternatively, you could use this:

```
#include "limits.h"
/* ... */
#if SHRT_BIT == CHAR_BIT * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find a solution to this problem, but I removed the if's and left behind the line that would be processed anyway and the program compiled just fine. I really don't know what was wrong with this file.